# monitor user acrivity

Tags: security, monitoring

How can we secure and monitor access for an external contractor when accessing an UBUNTU machine?

- how to track bash history changes (line deletion ..etc)
- how to track all his activities in general (best practices and recommendations)

Comment: You cannot, if the EC is going to do system-level things (has access to `root`  /`sudo`). If you don't trust the EC, and think EC won't be constrained by a Statement-of-Work or Non-Disclosure Agreements, don't grant access. I've been EC, and I've been in your position. Make sure EC has his/her own userid, don't share passwords. Perform a Threat/Risk Assessment of EC access. What do you want EC to do/not do? Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: thanks for your answer , i dont want him to delete lines from his history (all shells) (or a way to keep the full version of his history) , Ubunutu version : 22.04